# Añadir imagen en un header de un documento LaTeX

Tags: latex

Estoy intentando crear un header personalizado en LaTeX en el cual se sitúe a la izquierda del mismo, una imagen con el logo de la universidad y a la derecha la numeración del capitulo y justo debajo del número, el nombre de la sección, tal y como se muestra en [esta imagen.](https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/05/02/JECt2.png)

A continuación adjunto el código LaTex que crea el header con la numeración pero que falla al mostrar la imagen. [Resultado final deseado](https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/05/02/Jc0XB.png)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,spanish,english]{book}

\input{utils/super_macro}
\twosidelayout % default twoside layout active
\checkforceprintable

\input{utils/imports}
\input{utils/macros}
\input{utils/mute_warnings}

\showtodos{false}

% NECESSARY TITLE & AUTHOR
\title{\THETITLE}
\author{\THEAUTHOR}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

% define new section style
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}

% set header and footer
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{imagenes/logo.jpg}}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\setlength{\headheight}{2.5cm}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % apply TOC styles frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
\SetHeaderTitle{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\protect\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par\protect\thispagestyle{phdfancyempty}}
\protect\pagestyle{phdfancyspecialempty}

\ifexpandsubsublevel
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % numbering depth for section levels
\else
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % numbering depth for section levels
\fi

\mainmatter % apply TOC styles mainmatter

\begin{startpagenumbering}[1]
    \input{chapters/00_introduction}
\end{startpagenumbering}

\end{document}
```

[Demo en overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/4688491886yxkvytqjczkq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es utilizar un entorno `picture`, el cual permite usar dentro el comando `\put` para poner cualquier contenido (lo que incluye un `\includegraphics`) donde quieras dentro del entorno picture.

Según esta idea, se trataría de poner justo al lado del número "gordo" que es el título del capítulo, un entorno `picture` de ancho y alto 0 (de modo que su contenido no influye en el resto del layout), y dentro de ese entorno usar `\put` para poner la imagen donde quieras. Ya que el entorno se situaría justo detrás del número de capítulo, las coordenadas usadas en `\put` serían relativas a la posición de ese número de capítulo.

Empezamos por definir el formato de capítulo con `titlesec` para incluir al lado del número de capítulo una llamada a una macro `\putlogo` que escribiremos después:

```latex
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{%
    \vspace{-4.8cm}\flushright%
    \fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}%
    {\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont% Ahora va el numero de capitulo
    \textcolor{gray75}\thechapter\hsp\putlogo}% y hemos incluido aqui lo de \putlogo
    {0pt}{\\ \vspace{-1cm}\Huge\bfseries}[\titlerule\vspace{-1cm}]
```

Seguidamente escribimos la macro `\putlogo` que hace uso del entorno picture como expliqué antes:

```latex
\def\putlogo{\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
  \put(-16.5,-1.5){\includegraphics[width=4cm]{imagenes/logo.jpg}}%
  \end{picture}}
```

Los números mágicos `-16.5` y `-1.5` los encontré un poco por ensayo y error, pero simplemente significan "16.5cm a la izquierda y 1.5 por debajo del punto donde aparezca la macro `\putlogo`", en nuestro caso, relativo al número del capítulo.

Ahora, al crear un capítulo:

```latex
\chapter{Demostracion}
```

el resultado se ve así:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!